# Send sharing invitation not working for emails that do not have an existing MSA account or is already added to AAD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The invitation email does not get sent out when the recipient email do not have an existing MSA account or is already added to AAD

Comment: Jorgen - please provide more details.  There isn't enough information here to provide any answers.  What APIs in Microsoft Graph are you calling and what are you passing in the request, such that you are expecting an invitation email?

Comment: We are calling POST /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/invite

Comment: With requiresignin and sendinvitation true

Comment: Doc link: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_invite

Comment: Here is a sample request and response: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!93qFcpe6I0-v1tYpYpl6OQa89s_hTxNAg9kSsTlOBqajRqOF3ec-Rp6uqtbLNt4w/items/0154OD4RMAHEPYR4ECQRCJIZYNHQN5XTD6/invite

{"recipients":[{"email":"xxxxxx@gmail.com"}],"message":"Test","requireSignIn":true,"sendInvitation":true,"roles":["write"]}

Comment: Response: Response:    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
request-id: 60ad61c4-a94a-4e5f-bf53-eca3c1fa1db3
client-request-id: 60ad61c4-a94a-4e5f-bf53-eca3c1fa1db3
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
Duration: 2325.8296
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "60ad61c4-a94a-4e5f-bf53-eca3c1fa1db3",
      "date": "2017-03-17T11:22:27"
    }
  }
}    @dan

Comment: I couldn't repro this.  That API worked for me.  I'll try and get someone else to take a look...

Comment: Jorgen: Is the account sending the API request a OneDrive for Business account or a OneDrive personal account?

Comment: OneDrive for Business. And it is actually inviting on a folder inside a Office 365 group. Used to work fine.